# N number of positions, 3 particles, sum must equal zero

Tags: combinatorics

Please, I'm having a serious problem in my scifi work, and I'm not really good at math.

I have N positions available for three different particles. Each particle has an intrinsic number assigned to it.

Particle A is assigned a +1; Particle B a 0; Particle C a -1.

Assuming that

1)The order of the positions do not matter;

2)The total sum of the combination must be zero,

how many possibilities of combinations do I have? Could you please explain your reasoning?

Thanks.

Comment: That is not totally clear to me.  Could you give an example, e.g. with $N=4$

Comment: We would have 4 spaces, so a combination could be like
A,B,B,C (+1+0+0-1=0) would be the same as B,A,C,B

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Isn't this rather trivial? Or maybe I misunderstand. There must be the same number of A as C, and the rest is all B. So for N=4 you can have 0, 1 or 2 of A, which determines the rest to give BBBB, ABBC, and AACC. For larger N, the number of A can range from 0 to floor(N/2) for a total of 1+floor(N/2) possible arrangements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the number $a$ of $A$ particles must equal the number $c$ of $C$ particles, and the remaining $b$ positions must be $B$ particles.
This is in order for the sum to be $0$.
In particular, we have $N-b=a+c=2a$, that is, $N-b$ is even and hence $N$ and $b$ are the same parity.

Hence, the number of possible combinations is the number of distinct solutions to

$$2a+b=N$$

where $a,b\geq 0$ are integers.

---

### Case $(1)$: $N = 2k$

When $N$ is even, the solutions are uniquely determined by the values of $a=0,1,\dots,k$ for a total of $k+1$ solutions.

---

### Case $(2)$: $N = 2k+1$

When $N$ is odd, we *must* have at least one $B$ particle $($ie, $b\geq 1)$.
Since order does not matter, the remaining $2k$ positions can be counted according to case $(1)$, so we once again have $k+1$ solutions.

---

### Conclusion

In short, we can say there are $\left\lfloor N/2\right\rfloor +1$ possible arrangements.

Comment: Ohhh I see, it was much more simple than I thought. Thank you for the explanation.